# value should be empty, if data has no value using lodash

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, lodash

I am trying to use lodash for the following scenario:
If data is `null` or `undefined?, then value has to show empty - using Lodash.

```
 this.PartServiceData.masterData = result['data'].partMasterDataCompleteList[0];
```

In the code above, if any data has `undefined` or `null` value, data has to be written empty, using a Lodash method.

Comment: `has to written empty` what does that mean? Write to the console? what is `empty`?

Comment: maybe you want lodash.get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) with the `default value` parameter then you can assign `empty` when the value is `null/undefined` in one call.

```
_.get(result, 'data.partMasterDataCompleteList.0', 'empty');
```